How to set an asynchronous validation when I use superRefine method in zod
I'm trying to use an asynchronous validation on superRefine in zod but I got this error: Async refinement encountered during synchronous parse operation. Use .parseAsync instead.
I'm trying to register an user. I'm using prisma as a database access.
import { prisma } from '../../../helper/prisma'
import { z } from 'zod'

export const registerSchema = z.object({
    email: z.string().min(1, {
        message: "Email field is required"
    }).trim().email({
        message: "Email is invalid"
    }),
    password: z.string().min(7, {
        message: "Password must have more than 6 characters"
    }).trim(),
    confirm: z.string().trim().min(1, {
        message: "Confirm password field is required"
    })
}).superRefine(async ({ password, confirm, username, email }, ctx) => { // Set asynchronous validation

    const emailExists = await prisma.user.findUnique({ // This does not work
        where: {
            email
        }
    })

    if (emailExists) {
        ctx.addIssue({
            code: "custom",
            message: "The email already exists",
            path: ["email"]
        })
    }

})


The error means that you try to parse you schema synchronously, which won't work anymore as you now have an asynchronous validation.
So instead of parsing your schema like this
registerSchema.parse({ email: "john@example.com" })

You need to call it like this
await registerSchema.parseAsync({ email: "john@example.com" })


I think @robinvdvleuten is saying that there's no problem with the code listed in the question, but with how the z.object schema gets used afterward. Is that correct, @robinvdvleuten?

yes thats indeed correct
